# Reversablity of dehydration

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrolysis

Aqueous magnesium bicarbonate when evaporated decomposes into magnesium carbonate. Is that reaction reversible by dissolving the carbonate in soda water?

Comment: What was that carbolic supposed to mean?

Comment: Isn't carbolic the old way of saying phenol (or phenoxide in this case, possibly).

Comment: yes should read carbonic acid

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact this process is similar to the processes in lime stone that form cave stalagmite and stalactites but with calcium carbonates.
$$\ce{M(HCO3)2 <-> MCO3 + H2O + CO2 }$$
$$\ce{M} = (\ce{Mg},\ce{Ca})$$
Though I should note the process in not called dehydration.